# Finding the probability of having a genetic trait given test is positive

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I've been doing this question but I'm a little stuck on the second part. The first part is as follows:

The probability of a randomly selected person in a population having a particular genetic trait is 0.00001. A test for this trait successfully detects it, if present, 99.9% of the time, and only returns a false positive 0.1% of the time. A person tests positive for the trait. Find the probability that they actually have the genetic trait. Give your answer to 3 significant figures.

To approach this problem, I defined the following events:
A - the person has the genetic trait and B - the test detects the trait.

Based on the information in the question, we have:
$$P(A)=0.00001$$ $$P(B|A)=0.999$$ $$P(B|!A)=0.001$$

The question asks for $P(A|B)$ and so I thought to apply Bayes:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

To find $P(B)$, I used the total probability:
$$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|!A)P(!A)$$

Substituting in the values, I got $P(A|B)=0.00989$ to 3 significant figures. The second part goes like this:

In order to improve accuracy, individuals are instructed to take the test twice, regardless of the result of the first test. What is the probability that an individual receives a positive result from both tests? Give your answer to 3 significant figures. Find the probability, given that they have tested positive twice, that they actually have the genetic trait. Give your answer to 3 significant figures.

I'm not quite sure how to formulate this problem in terms of the events I defined previously.

Comment: We'll have to make some sort of assumptions about the independence or dependence of these events (*typically a terrible assumption to make in reality, as the test trying to detect the trait will likely continue to detect what it was looking for or continue to fail to detect whatever it was since conditions have not changed between tests*).  Letting $C$ be the event that the person tests positive for the trait in the second test (*while $B$ is for the first test*), I would assume they intend for $\Pr(B\cap C\mid A)=\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(C\mid A)$ and so on...

Comment: That is to say, $B$ and $C$ are conditionally independent given $A$, i.e. if a person with the trait takes the test, each test will detect it at the same rate and independently of one another, and similarly for if the person does not have the trait.  Note that this does not imply that $B$ and $C$ are independent... the first test implying they do have the trait will cause us to believe the second test will give the same result moreso than giving a random result.

Comment: So $P(B|A)=P(C|A)$ in this scenario?

Comment: I would assume so, yes, and $\Pr(B)=\Pr(C)$ and $\Pr(B\mid \neg A)=\Pr(C\mid \neg A)$ and so on... but to emphasize, $\Pr(C\mid B)$ will not equal $1$, it is (*presumably*) possible for you to get a positive result on the first test while getting a negative result on the second test (*otherwise it makes no sense to administer the test twice and expect it to "improve accuracy"*).  To emphasize... this is an assumption, and the question author should have done a better job clarifying this point.

Comment: Well $P(B|A).P(C|A)=0.998$ which is incorrect?

Comment: What do you suppose $\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(C\mid A)$ represents?  What are you trying to calculate?  The probability that the person tests positive in both tests *in general*?  Or that *given that a person truly has the trait* that they test positive in both tests?

Comment: I think the question wants to calculate the probability that the person tests positive in both tests in general, at least the first part of the second section.

Comment: Exactly... so I ask again, why did you try to calculate $\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(C\mid A)$?  This is not going to give you the answer to that question.

Comment: Would I just need to calculate $P(B).P(C)$?

Comment: Again, no.  $B$ and $C$ are not going to be independent... they are merely *conditionally* independent *given* $A$.  That is not the same thing.  You do need to calculate $\Pr(B\cap C)$, but this does not expand as $\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$. Try expanding it out via total probability by conditioning on $A$ vs $\neg A$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be defined as before but with $B$ specifically being in reference to the results of the first test.  Let $C$ be defined similarly to $B$ but with $C$ being in reference to the results of the second test.

Let us assume that the question author intends that a person who takes the test who has the condition gets the results of the two tests independently of one another... similarly for someone who does not have the condition.  That is... $\Pr(B)=\Pr(C),~\Pr(B\mid A)=\Pr(C\mid A),~\Pr(B\mid \neg A)=\Pr(C\mid \neg A)$ and that $\Pr(B\cap C\mid A)=\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(C\mid A)$ as well as $\Pr(B\cap C\mid \neg A)=\Pr(B\mid \neg A)\Pr(C\mid \neg A)$.  Admittedly, this is a very heavy assumption which is generally not going to be true in practice, but without this assumption it makes no sense to try to repeat the test and expect that it will improve accuracy.

---

Let us try to find the probability that a randomly selected person (*ignoring whether they have the condition or not*) tests positive twice in a row.  That would be $\Pr(B\cap C)$ but recall that $B$ and $C$ will not be independent, merely *conditionally* independent... so we may not simply expand as $\Pr(B\cap C)=\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$.  We approach instead by the law of total probability and expand by using $A$ and what we know (*and assumed*).

$\begin{array}{rll}\Pr(B\cap C) &= \Pr(B\cap C\mid A)\Pr(A)+\Pr(B\cap C\mid \neg A)\Pr(\neg A)&\text{by total probability}\\&=\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(C\mid A)\Pr(A)+\Pr(B\mid\neg A)\Pr(C\mid \neg A)\Pr(\neg A)&\text{by assumption}\\&=0.999\cdot 0.999\cdot 0.00001 + 0.001\cdot 0.001\cdot 0.99999&\text{plugging in numbers}\\&=0.00001097001&\text{evaluate}\end{array}$

Now, we wish to find $\Pr(A\mid (B\cap C))$.  To do this, we do as before by Bayes' Theorem.

$$\begin{array}{rll}\Pr(A\mid (B\cap C)) &= \dfrac{\Pr(B\cap C\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B\cap C)}&\text{by Bayes'}\\&=\dfrac{\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(C\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B\cap C)}&\text{by assumption}\\&=\dfrac{0.999\cdot 0.999\cdot 0.00001}{0.00001097001}&\text{plugging in}\\&\approx 0.90975395646859\dots&\text{evaluate}\end{array}$$